# exception handling on a ajax call on azure cloudservice

Tags: ajax, exception, elmah, azure-web-roles

I have an azure Webrole (cloudservice).

I have installed Elmah on it to send us the exceptions.

Works fine locally (IIS-express/AzureEmulator)

But on the real azure environment, it ain't logging the exceptions caused in ajaxcalls on the server.
All not-ajaxcall raised exception, are logged and we get a e-mail for.

We have a MVC4Webapplication on it. And the methods being called by ajax are MVC-controller methods.

Anyone who have a clue why it wont work on Azure itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution in this blog ->
http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-4--handleerrorattribute

By adding the custom HandleErrorAttribute problem was fixed.

View full blog post -> http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-1--setup

At the bottom whole list of all parts, this one is very usefull.

Enjoy.